# Why doesn't JavaScript recognize this output from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have jQuery doing a post to PHP, like this:

```
$.post("/contact/edit_contact", serialized).done(
    function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            $('#row-' + id).html(response.html); 
        } else {
            alert("There was a problem saving");
        }
```

The PHP that handles it returns this response (in the network tab):

```
<div> 
    A bunch of HTML...
</div>

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /.../contact.controller.php:56) in /.../include/App.class.php on line 82

Call Stack:
    0.0005     683376   1. {main}() pathTo/index.php:0
    ....       
     pathTo/contact.controller.php:58
    0.6205    6286496   6. header() pathTo/App.class.php:82

{"success":true,"html":"<div>\n .... </div>"}
```

But when I do `console.log(response.success)` I get "undefined".

Why doesn't JavaScript/jQuery promises see that response.success is set to true?

Comment: Because taken as a whole the response is just a big confused mishmash of nothing in particular. If the `"success":true` part were embedded in the middle of the text of Moby Dick would you expect jQuery to magically determine what you meant?

Comment: Is the question why the javascript isn't properly parsing the "headers already sent" error that PHP produces ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are important here; first of all, the code that's output must *only* contain the JSON you want returned. If you remove the HTML that is output before, you'll most likely also solve the PHP error that's returned.

When you're down to having only this in your return from the server...

```
{"success":true,"html":"<div>\n .... </div>"}
```

... you have to interpret it as JSON. The best way of doing this is through PHP by sending a header:

```php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

But in any case, you can tell jQuery to interpret the response as JSON regardless by adding the following line first in your `done`-function:

```js
response = $.parseJSON(response);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also add `'json'` as a parameter to `$.post` (after the callback) to tell jQuery to parse it for you.

Comment: And you can create that JSON-formatted string by using `json_encode`.

Answer (score 6):

Because there's a bunch of stuff before the JSON-formatted string.

Why do you output HTML (and try to modify headers) before the JSON string?